# @AppStorage inside ObservableObject - How is `objectWillChange` triggered from inside the property wrapper?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, property-wrapper

In iOS 14.5, Apple made a change to `@AppStorage` so that it can be properly used within an `ObservableObject`:

> AppStorage property wrappers now work as expected when contained inside an ObservableObject, causing the system to emit the objectWillChange publisher. (65562845)

- Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes

How do they manage to call the `ObservableObject`'s `objectWillChange` publisher from within the `@AppStorage` property wrapper? Are are they using some internal API? Or is it possible to do that with any property wrapper?

I know that one part of this "magic" is the `DynamicProperty` protocol. But that alone is not enough to trigger an `objectWillChange` event. My guess would be that it's the same logic they used for `@Published`, which - as far as I know - also can't really be "reserve engineered" right now.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-wrappers-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that article covers this question.

Comment: If to subscribe to objectWillChange publisher in this case and set breakpoint in handler closure then there is nothing in stack about UserDefaults usage or anything similar, so IMO it is direct internal *magic* call (like direct access to property owner from within property wrapper, what was requested for public usage for a long time), but I of course might be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I fear as well. Let's hope this changes with WWDC22. Thanks for checking! :)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked there was a class extension that modifies the class to add the call to `objectWillChange.send()` in the `willSet` of `@Published` properties and I assume also `@AppStorage` properties. I remember also if you define `objectWillChange` yourself then these mechanics get turned off. When I reverse engineered it, the code looked very fragile to me and I did think it maybe safer to just call `objectWillSend` myself.